# Link/unlink buttons missing in Wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I can't wrap my head around this: the link and unlink buttons just don't show in the TinyMCE editor. I tried to include them with the `mce_buttons` filter as well, but with no luck.

Where should I look?

[image: Screenshot of TinyMCE editor]

Comment: What plugins are you loading?  Do any of them interact with the TinyMCE editor?

Comment: None, actually. I installed TinyMCE Advanced, but then the link buttons were only displaying when I used the plugins own link insert dialog!

Comment: Okay, I solved it myself. I had put in this code `add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojicons_tinymce' );` Thanks for giving it your attention, @MichaelFromin

Comment: glad you got it figured out!

Comment: I removed `add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojicons_tinymce' )` and buttons showed up

Answer (score 5):

Removing `add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojicons_tinymce' )`
from the functions.php file worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a solution for this unlink button missing from WordPress version 4.9 then I found this thread https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unlink-in-editor-menu/#post-9964651

Then I installed [WP Edit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-edit/) & [TinyMCE Advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/). Both the plugin back my needed unlink button without any configuration. Just installed and checked editor page, you can try yourself.

[Check My Editor's Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlK9V.png)